# Choose different colors for the thumb for a React Native Switch on Android

Tags: android, react-native

I have the following component:

```
<Switch trackColor={{true: COLORS.accent, false: COLORS.grey}} style={styles.switch} value={this.state.notifyOnEntry} onValueChange={(value) => {this.onToggle('notifyOnEntry', value)}} />
```

I want to change the `thumbColor` and set it two different colours for when it is enabled or disabled as I did it for the trackColor. I was expecting this to be the same as for `trackColor` but `thumbColor` is a single colour and not an object.

Is it possible to change it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can provide the color by a condition like below

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { View, Switch, StyleSheet } from "react-native";

export default function App() {
  const [isEnabled, setIsEnabled] = useState(false);
  const toggleSwitch = () => setIsEnabled(previousState => !previousState);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Switch
        trackColor={{ false: "#767577", true: "#81b0ff" }}
        thumbColor={isEnabled ? COLORS.accent : COLORS.grey}
        ios_backgroundColor="#3e3e3e"
        onValueChange={toggleSwitch}
        value={isEnabled}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

You can also use notifyOnEntry for the condition instead of the isenabled value.

Comment: for the people that like me are new to react. You need to add `import React, { useState } from 'react'`